# Skipping SKActions

Tags: macos, sprite-kit, skaction

At the beginning of my scene I'm running a bunch of different actions as a sort of intro to the level. I would like to make it skippable by the user. Is there a way to handle this with SKAction? SKAction is my bet, but perhaps there's a better way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: skippable... If you mean on tap on screen and the action completes, then you need to remember what the actions are, and on touch just kill all current actions and rerun them with a duration of 0 (or just manually set whatever the complete event is) ,  if you mean to just stop all actions, then you can just remove them.  Best way to do this, give your actions keys, and call `removeActionForKey`  Not sure if there is something else needed, that is why I didn't make this an answer.

Comment: That's genius...I never thought about running them with a duration of 0. Make an answer and I'll accept. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes you want tap to stop the actions:

A very easy but possibly unstable approach would be to just crank the speed of the Node the action is running on to an insanely high number, just remember to reset it if you need the node.

An easy approach that is more stable would be to save your actions and reapply them with a duration of zero.

The best way to do this is to create a `Dictionary` for your `SKAction`s like so:

```
var actionDict = [String,SKAction]()
```

Then just save all your actions with keys so that you can access it in the future:

```
actionDict["moveUp"] = SKAction.moveToY(100,duration:100)
```

Now that you have keys for it,  when running your actions, just assign the same key:

```
node.runAction(actionDict["moveUp"],withKey:"moveUp")
```

Then when you need to end it, just remove the desired actions:

```
node.removeActionForKey("moveUp")
```

And reapply with a duration of 0:

```
//if we want to retain the old duration, use copy
let action = actionDict["moveUp"].copy()
action.duration = 0
node.runAction(action,withKey:"moveUp")
```

Note,  this method only works where the action is doing a To event,  if it is doing a By event, you need to figure out the final destination point, and make it a moveTo a with duration of 0